# c# deserialize json with unknown input

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I am trying to deserialize a json which I get from a public web service (I have no access on it). This json has a key let's call it "termene" and for this key the value is sometimes a list and sometimes just a string. and I get the following error in visual studio:

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List Because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObject Attribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
```

I am  using the following code:

```
List<DosareICCJ> result;
var url = "some url that works";

var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);


var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream());

var callresult = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DosareICCJ>>(callresult);

return result;
```

the "termene" key is defined like this in the class "DosareICCJ"

```
public List<TermeneICCJ> termene { get; set; }

   public class DosareICCJ
{
    public string ora { get; set; }
    public string numar { get; set; }
    public string numarVechi { get; set; }
    public DateTime? data { get; set; }
    public DateTime? dataInitiala { get; set; }
    public string categorieCaz { get; set; }
    public string departament { get; set; }
    public string obiect { get; set; }
    public string obiecteSecundare { get; set; }
    public string stadiuProcesual { get; set; }
    public string stadiulProcesualCombinat { get; set; }
    public List<PartiICCJ> parti { get; set; }      
    public List<TermeneICCJ> termene { get; set; }
    public List<CaiAtacICCJ> caiAtac { get; set; }
}
public class TermeneICCJ
{
    public DateTime? data { get; set; }
    public string ora { get; set; }
    public string SedintaDeJudecata { get; set; }
    public string complet { get; set; }
    public string numarDocument { get; set; }
    public DateTime? dataDocument { get; set; }
    public string tipDocument { get; set; }
    public string solutie { get; set; }
    public string detaliiSolutie { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So it's either `List<DosareICCJ>` or just `DosareICCJ`? Could try to use try-catch around the first approach and fall back to the other one.

Comment: the code snippet should return a list, everything shoud be a list. I was thinking of the try-catch approach but I only get one big json with a lot of "DosareICCJ"s so everything needs to work in one go

Comment: Can you share the different variations of JSON?

Comment: yes, the two of them can be found here
https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/51gi
sorry for the format
try to search for "termene"

Comment: @patrumarian you have to post TermeneICCJ class at least if you want some help

Comment: It is old thread but I think it answers your issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994685/how-to-handle-both-a-single-item-and-an-array-for-the-same-property-using-json-n

Comment: One of the converters from [How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18994685/3744182) should meet your needs.  Deserialize to `List<DosareICCJ>` and add `SingleOrArrayConverter<DosareICCJ>` to your converters list.